# Problem with gdal in C# to reproject raster

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, c#, gdalwarp

I wrote this simple code below in C# to convert a raster from Lambert Azimutal Equal Area to regular long-lat raster using GDAL. It works quite fine excepted for the zero-value bands on each side, in purple in the image. I understand that those area would have the nodata_value (i.e. -9999) in turn of zero.

---

Using comments to this question I found that using a .vrt file and adding this to the   <GDALWarpOptions> section:

```
<Option name="INIT_DEST">-9999</Option>
```

it works!  So my problem now is **how to add this option programmatically**, intended that I'm using a AutoCreateWarpedVRT.

```
            Dataset ds = Gdal.Open(file, Access.GA_ReadOnly);
            SpatialReference sss = new OSGeo.OSR.SpatialReference(null);
            sss.ImportFromProj4("+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m");
            string srs_wkt;
            sss.ExportToWkt(out srs_wkt);

            SpatialReference ttt = new OSGeo.OSR.SpatialReference(null);
            ttt.ImportFromProj4("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84");
            string trs_wkt;
            ttt.ExportToWkt(out trs_wkt);

            Dataset tgs = Gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT(ds, srs_wkt, trs_wkt, ResampleAlg.GRA_NearestNeighbour, 0);

            Driver ddf = Gdal.GetDriverByName("AAIGrid");
            ddf.CreateCopy(@"out.asc", tgs, 1, null, null, null);
```

[image]

Comment: I guess that you don't deal with nodata. Perhaps this Python example helps https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/87699/gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT.

Comment: Almost duplicates https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26325/reproject-script-in-python-with-gdal https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158503/9999-no-data-value-becomes-0-when-writing-array-to-gdal-memory-file

Comment: @user30184 thanks, I've read this other question but they say: "If I add this line into the rgbwarped.vrt generated in the second step everything is OK:

<Option name="UNIFIED_SRC_NODATA">YES</Option>

C++ applications can set this option directly. Applications using AutoCreateWarpedVRT from SWIG binding must add this line in to the text of the produced VRT manually."  As I use AutoCreateWarpedVRT , I didn't figure out how to add this option???  I've found no "setOption" method or something like that in the API....

Comment: [This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158503/9999-no-data-value-becomes-0-when-writing-array-to-gdal-memory-file) is for python but might have some clues on setting the nodata value.